# Design Dilemma - Context or Contract? (Java/Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, android-context, design-by-contract

I have an `Activity`, a `Presenter`, and a `Contract` which both the `Activity` and the `Presenter` implement. The `Activity` will have some unique UI stuff, which must be called from within the `Presenter`. The `Presenter` must also be able to make a call to the Activity (e.g. `sendBroadcast()`) which takes advantage of the fact that an `Activity` is also a `Context`.

Here is my conundrum: If I pass `Context` to the `Presenter`, I lose access to the UI methods unique to the `Activity`; if I pass the `Contract.View` to the `Presenter`, I lose access to the methods that require `Context`. The only solutions I can think of are:

A) Pass both the `Context` AND the `Contract.View` to the `Presenter` (which will always be the same Object, i.e. the `Activity`) OR

B) Ditch the *Design-by-Contract* pattern altogether and just directly pass the `Activity` to the `Presenter`

---

Both seem like rally bad ideas...What is the recommended approach here? Below is a scaled down version of the code I am currently working with:

#### Activity.kt

```
class Activity: AppCompatActivity(), Contract.View {

    private lateinit var mPresenter: Contract.Presenter

    @BindView(R.id.textView)
    private lateinit var mTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
        mPresenter = Presenter(this)
    }

    override fun updateText(text: String) {
        mTextView.text = text
    }

}
```

#### Presenter.kt

```
// Pass Context or Contract.View as parameter to constructor?
class Presenter(private val ???: ???): Contract.Presenter {

    fun discoverService() {
        val intent: Intent = // ...

        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    override fun setServiceCommInfo() {
        mView.updateText(Acquiring Data from Service...)
        // ...
    }

}
```

#### Contract.kt

```
interface Contract {

    interface View {
        updateText(text: String)
    }

    interface Presenter {
        setServiceCommInfo()
    }

}
```

Comment: So far I understand, the problem can be solved by a mixture of both strategy and decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A. Passing both to presenter. I found it cleaner and more SOLID.
But honestly, I'm using just java from the tags.
Hope it was something!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that's "less ugly" (ugly is a very subjective term) than the two I mentioned in my original post. Basically the idea here is to identify that

1. `mContext` and `Contract.View` will always be the same object
2. An object O is considered to be an instance of interface I if O implements I

Adding the following code to **Presenter.kt** will make it unnecessary to pass the same object twice:

```
class Presenter(private val mContext: Context): Contract.Presenter {

    private lateinit var mView: Contract.View

    init {
        if (mContext is Contract.View) mView = mContext
    }

}
```